# Javascript code for AWS authentication using REST (no AWS SDK)

Tags: javascript, rest, http-post, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I have a webapp in Javascript and I need to authenticate users with AWS Cognito and then read/create/change records in DynamoDB.

But I can't use AWS SDK!

How can it be done using HTTP POST?
Any suggestion where I can find some example code in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any prior implementation which calls Cognito APIs from Javascript without the AWS SDK but you are more than welcome to try it.

You can reverse engineer our [Javascript SDK](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-js) to write this code. [Cognito documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/index.html) and [Javascript SDKs API reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html) will guide you through the concepts and flows you should follow.

[This blog](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxBVEDL5Z8JKAC/Use-Amazon-Cognito-in-your-website-for-simple-AWS-authentication) is generally a very helpful starter guide for Javascript developers.